# How many numbers greater than $10,000$ and less than $35,000$ can you write with the numbers $1, 2, 5, 6, 8$ if numbers must not repeat?

Tags: combinatorics

I just can't figure this one out:

How many numbers greater than $10,000$ and less than $35,000$ can you write with the numbers: $1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8$  if

a) numbers must not repeat
b) numbers can repeat.

The answer to a) is $2 \cdot V(5, 4) + 2 \cdot V(4, 3) = 288$.

Can someone please explain the logic behind this? Why do you need to multiply both variations with 2?

Comment: The term variations means permutations.  Hence, $$V(n, k) = P(n, k) = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider cases:

**Case 1:**  The leading digit is $1$ or $2$.

We have two choices for the leading digit.  That leaves us with four positions to fill.  We select those four digits from the five digits that were not used in the leading digit, which we can do in $V(5, 4)$ ways.  Hence, the number of numbers we can form with leading digit $1$ or $2$ is $2 \cdot V(5, 4)$.

**Case 2:**  The leading digit is $3$.

We have one choice for the leading digit.  Since we can not use $3$ again, the thousands digit must be $1$ or $2$.  That leaves us with three positions to fill.  We select those three digits from the four digits that were not used in the ten thousands place or thousands place, which we can do in $V(4, 3)$ ways.  Hence, the number of numbers we can form with leading digit $3$ is $2 \cdot V(4, 3)$.

Answer (score 1):

First digit can be 1 or 2 – that accounts for the first 2.

If first digit is 3, second digit can be 1 or 2 – that accounts for the second 2.